# how to implement calendar with month+week+day view

Tags: android, view, calendar, implementation

i am developing an android app and i need activity which contains calendar view which can be viewed with day, week and month view.
i searched everywere but didnt find anything that work,
Thanks!

Comment: Here is custom date & time picker dialogs. You can easily include this in your project
http://android-arsenal.com/tag/27

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't a proper question but a code request. However, If I had to make a calendar would begin learning how to use [Calendar View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) an Android widget since API 11. For example, with this tutorial: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/android-calendarview-example/